# data loss in file transfer - JAVA?

Tags: java, file-io

i have a FileServer and a FileClient, server sends a file, when client connects. it is a simple program, just to understand the concept behind.

I am able to send the file from Server to Client, with a buffer of 1024.
The problem is that the recieved file is always around 0.01 MB less than the original file.Thus mp3 files lose some info, and video files just doesn't play.

I put some prinln statements in my while loops in both Server & Client. i found that my server is not sending the whole file.

```
  //Server
  byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [1024];    
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
  OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
  System.out.println("Sending...\n mybytearray length:"+mybytearray.length+"file   length:"+(int)myFile.length());
  int read, readTotal=0;
  while ((read = fis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length)) != -1) { 

      os.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
      System.out.println("File REad:"+read+"readtotal:"+readTotal); //*
      readTotal += read;
}
  System.out.println("Final File Read:"+read+" Final readtotal:"+readTotal);
  os.flush();
  sock.close();
  }
```

The Println statement output is:

```
Sending...
mybytearray length:1024file length:12767554
File REad:1024readtotal:0
File REad:1024readtotal:1024
.............and a lot of it...and then
File REad:1024readtotal:12756992
File REad:1024readtotal:12758016
File REad:322readtotal:12759040
Final File Read:-1 Final readtotal:12759362
```

The file length:12767554 & Last readTotal: 12759362 shud be equal. i don't understand why the last read value is lower [322], while it can still have 1024.

Any kind of help wud be appreciated.
Thanks.

[EDIT]

```
//Client
int read;
int totalRead = 0;

while ((read = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length)) != -1) {
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , read);

        totalRead += read;
        System.out.println("\nread:"+read+"\ntotalread: "+totalRead);
}
System.out.println("Final File Read:"+read+" Final readtotal:"+totalRead);
bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , read);  //57 Line in FileClient.java
bos.flush();
```

i again tried to send a file. a txt this time.
this is my server's output

```
Sending...
mybytearray length:1024file length:1232
File REad:1024readtotal:0
File REad:208readtotal:1024
Final File Read:-1 Final readtotal:1232
```

and this one on client

```
read:208
totalread: 1232
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
   Final File Read:-1     Final readtotal:1232

at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at FileClient.main(FileClient.java:57)
```

readtotal values are same, but sometimes i get this error, sometimes i don't.

**[BIG EDIT--COMPLETE CLIENT CODE]**

```
public class FileClient{
 public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
final JFrame f = new JFrame("Sample");
f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(590,490);
f.setVisible(true);
// localhost for testing
Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",13267);
System.out.println("Connecting...");
File f1=new File(RecieveObject(sock));


// receive file
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [1024];
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();


FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f1);
ProgressMonitorInputStream nn= new ProgressMonitorInputStream(f,"reading",is);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
 /*   bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
current = bytesRead;


do {
   bytesRead =
      is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
   System.out.println("mybytesarray length: "+mybytearray.length+"\ncurrent:"+current+"\nbytesread: "+bytesRead);
   if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
} while(bytesRead > -1);

bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
bos.flush();
 */
int read;
int totalRead = 0;
//InputStream clientInputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
while ((read = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length)) != -1) {
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , read);

        totalRead += read;
        System.out.println("\nread:"+read+"\ntotalread: "+totalRead);
}
System.out.println("Final File Read:"+read+" Final readtotal:"+totalRead);
 //   bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , read);
bos.flush();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end-start);
bos.close();
sock.close();

}
public static  String RecieveObject(Socket s) {
    String str = null;
    try{
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());



            str =(String)is.readUTF();


    }
    catch(IOException ex){}
    return str;
}
```

}

Comment: i just saw the size of an video file i sent, was 41046 KB, after transferring it is now 41040 KB.i dont know where the 6 KB has gone?

Comment: after removing line 57 on client, i am not getting any error, but  i am still losing 6 KB on the file after transferring.

Comment: You might want to make a new question out of your last edit if your original question has been answered. One that is specific and points out the code that has the problem (where is line 57?)

Comment: Actually its the same problem that is kind of not yet solved, so i tht i shud not create a new one.... line 57 is the bos.write after while loop in client code. Just removed it, i am not getting an error , but i am still losing some 6 KB or sometimes 4KB of data??

Comment: Problem is kind of Solved, i surrounded the code with try/catch. and it worked with the same eg i used prev, no data loss this time, exactly getting 41046 KB, but this was temporary, now i am again losing some KB's, i have removed ProgressMonitor(although it was not working), now i will remove ObjectXXXXXXStreams from client/server, and will check ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the beginning of the file (up to the first 1024 bytes), due to your 5th line (including the comment).  You read from the input and advanced it, without sending it to the client.  Remove this:

```
bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
```

Additionally, you're not using the `BufferedInputStream` in your loop.  Either use `bis.read` here instead of `fis.read` (if you still want buffered reads) - or remove the `BufferedInputStream` all together.

Your other problem is that you're reading the final bytes on the client, then entering the loop once more. `is.read` is again called. Instead of returning -1, it's throwing an `IOException` as the other side of the socket has been closed. As such, bos.flush() and bos.close() aren't getting called, and your final bytes are never written to disk.  To assist with this, try calling `sock.shutdownOutput` before closing it.  Regardless, you'll want to add some proper exception handling around this.

Comment: yes i think i am missing the start part of the files, just listened to the mp3 file rcvd. i'll try that..

Comment: @NikharSharma - Does your `readTotal` still show a discrepancy?  Is it possible the missing bytes are now due to the client code (possibly due to a similar issue as the one that was here) instead of the server code?  Maybe you can post the client code as well?

Comment: I am including my client code, plz take a look, the last readTotal on client and server are equal..

Comment: @NikharSharma - `readTotal` shows as equal on both the client and server - but is it correct to assume that they both reflect 6KB less than the actual size of the file?

Comment: yes i think i shud not assume that, but then, where actually i am missing the data, the video in which i lost 6KB, didn't gave any error, but this time i tried a simple txt file of 1232 B, gave me an error.??

Comment: @NikharSharma - Again, on the client, you don't need the final `bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , read);`.  This would result in invalid output - but doesn't necessarily explain why you're getting the exception you are.  I think there may be additional helpful details in the omitted portions of the client code.  Also, please include what the actual, expected file size is for each sample.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6728/discussion-between-nikhar-sharma-and-ziesemer)

Answer (score 1):

```
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [1024];    
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
System.out.println("Sending...\n mybytearray length:"+mybytearray.length+"filelength:"+(int)myFile.length());
int read, readTotal=0;
while ((read = bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length)) != -1) { 
    os.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
    System.out.println("File REad:"+read+"readtotal:"+readTotal); //*
    readTotal += read;
}
System.out.println("Final File Read:"+read+" Final readtotal:"+readTotal);
os.flush();
sock.close();
}
```